# How to call a function every time component is displayed?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to React and working on a project to get a better grasp of all its concepts. I am currently building a time-tracking application, that allows users to track time across tasks from different projects.

I am using Redux and storing in my app state a list of `Projects` each with a list of `Tasks`. Each task has a `totalDurationInSeconds` property.

I want to create a Reports page. Currently on the reports page, I only want to display the total duration in seconds across all projects. When I first start the application, the time is 0. If I add a task to one of the projects, the time gets updated.

However, when I add a second task to either the same project or a different project, the value does not get updated and it still only displays the duration of the first task.

```
const ReportsPage: React.FC<Props> = (props): React.ReactElement => {
  const [totalDuration, setTotalDuration] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < props.projects.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; i < props.projects[i].tasks.length; i++) {
        setTotalDuration(totalDuration + props.projects[i].tasks[j].totalDurationInSeconds);
      }
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
  <p>Total time spent across all projects : {totalDuration}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My component is connected to the ReduxStore and `Props` is of type `StateProps & ReportsPageProps`.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop condition and increment is using i instead of j

this is what you want:

```
for (let i = 0; i < props.projects.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < props.projects[i].tasks.length; j++) {
        setTotalDuration(totalDuration + props.projects[i].tasks[j].totalDurationInSeconds);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When `useEffect` function used without any dependency it executed one time, but you want the `totalDuration` will update when any task added.

```
   useEffect(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < props.projects.length; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < props.projects[i].tasks.length; j++) {
            setTotalDuration(totalDuration + props.projects[i].tasks[j].totalDurationInSeconds);
          }
        }
      }, [props.projects])
```